# How come I can cast IWebDriver to IJavaScriptExecutor?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, inheritance, selenium

Can anyone explain this 'magic'?

```
public interface IWebDriver : ISearchContext, IDisposable
{
    string CurrentWindowHandle { get; }
    string PageSource { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string Url { get; set; }
    ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowHandles { get; }

    void Close();
    IOptions Manage();
    INavigation Navigate();
    void Quit();
    ITargetLocator SwitchTo();
}

public interface ISearchContext
{
    IWebElement FindElement(By by);
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(By by);
}

public interface IJavaScriptExecutor
{
    object ExecuteAsyncScript(string script, params object[] args);
    object ExecuteScript(string script, params object[] args);
}
```

how come

```
(this.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("console.log('wtf?')");
```

works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [main implementation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs) of `IWebDriver` [implements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L63) `IJavaScriptExecutor` and thus provides implementation [of those methods](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L424).

You haven't provided the code that shows how you instantiate your driver, but they all inherit from `RemoteWebDriver`: example is the [ChromeDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs#L60)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah default implementation is this, and when cast is happening it is actually `IWebDriver`-> `ChromeDriver` -> `RemoteWebDriver` -> `IJavaScriptExecutor`

```
public class RemoteWebDriver : IWebDriver, IDisposable, ISearchContext, IJavaScriptExecutor, IFindsById, IFindsByClassName, IFindsByLinkText, IFindsByName, IFindsByTagName, IFindsByXPath, IFindsByPartialLinkText, IFindsByCssSelector, IHasInputDevices, IHasCapabilities, IAllowsFileDetection
{
    protected static readonly TimeSpan DefaultCommandTimeout;

    public RemoteWebDriver(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities);
    public RemoteWebDriver(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities);
    public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities);
    public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout);

    public ICapabilities Capabilities { get; }
    protected ICommandExecutor CommandExecutor { get; }
    public string CurrentWindowHandle { get; }
    public virtual IFileDetector FileDetector { get; set; }
    public IKeyboard Keyboard { get; }
    public IMouse Mouse { get; }
    public string PageSource { get; }
    protected SessionId SessionId { get; }
    public string Title { get; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowHandles { get; }

    public void Close();
    protected virtual RemoteWebElement CreateElement(string elementId);
    public void Dispose();
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
    protected virtual Response Execute(string driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary<string, object> parameters);
    public object ExecuteAsyncScript(string script, params object[] args);
    public object ExecuteScript(string script, params object[] args);
    public IWebElement FindElement(By by);
    protected IWebElement FindElement(string mechanism, string value);
    public IWebElement FindElementByClassName(string className);
    public IWebElement FindElementByCssSelector(string cssSelector);
    public IWebElement FindElementById(string id);
    public IWebElement FindElementByLinkText(string linkText);
    public IWebElement FindElementByName(string name);
    public IWebElement FindElementByPartialLinkText(string partialLinkText);
    public IWebElement FindElementByTagName(string tagName);
    public IWebElement FindElementByXPath(string xpath);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(By by);
    protected ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(string mechanism, string value);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByClassName(string className);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByCssSelector(string cssSelector);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsById(string id);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByLinkText(string linkText);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByName(string name);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByPartialLinkText(string partialLinkText);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByTagName(string tagName);
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsByXPath(string xpath);
    public IOptions Manage();
    public INavigation Navigate();
    public void Quit();
    protected virtual void StartClient();
    protected void StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities);
    protected virtual void StopClient();
    public ITargetLocator SwitchTo();
}
```